# Changing table styling for mobile

Tags: html, css, mpmediaquery

I have styled a table element with some custom css, which effectively puts a pic above each of three columns of text.

This doesn't work on a mobile ( specifically iPhone 5 ) so I am struggling to re configure it to be 6 rows, i.e., pic / text under / pic / text under etc, all ranged left.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks
Jim

```
    <style>
    .row2{}
    .col2{margin: 12px; width: 26%; float:left}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px)
    {
    .row2{width: 100%; float: clear: both;}
    .col2{margin: 10px; width: 100%; float: clear: both;}   
    }  
    </style>

    <div class="row2">
        <div class="col2"><a href="http://tcf-consulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/stephen_rosling1.png"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-195" alt="stephen_rosling" src="http://tcf-consulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/stephen_rosling1.png" width="225" height="242" /></a></div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="http://tcf-consulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/john_orourke2.png"><img class="size-full wp-image-211 alignleft" alt="john_orourke" src="http://tcf-consulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/john_orourke2.png" width="225" height="242" /></a></div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="http://tcf-consulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tbc1.png"><img class="size-full wp-image-197 alignleft" alt="tbc" src="http://tcf-consulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tbc1.png" width="225" height="242" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col2"><strong>Stephen Rosling</strong> has worked in the UK financial services sector for over 25 years, holding senior customer management positions in Aviva, Friends Life, Friends Provident International. He is currently working with Lloyds Banking Group on a major transformational project.</div>
        <div class="col2"><strong>John O’Rorke</strong> has worked in the international financial services sector for over 30 years, holding senior management positions in the UK and Australia with Lloyd’s Life Assurance, Royal Insurance and the Prudential.</div>
        <div class="col2"><strong>Satya Narayanan</strong> has more than 20 years of working experience in Asia Pacific, largely in the telecommunication services sector. He held senior customer service positions in Lucent Technologies and Alcatel-Lucent. He now specialises in Customer Experience analysis in the areas of Netpromoter (NPS), Customer Satisfaction and employee engagement including survey design, execution, analysis and reporting. He is currently engaged with a major General Insurance group in Malaysia.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How do I add the link to jsfiddle? It says i need to add code? Which code??

Comment: The relevant code which reproduces this problem.

Comment: <style>
.row2{}
.col2{margin: 12px; width: 26%; float:left}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px)
{
.row2{width: 100%; float: clear: both;}
.col2{margin: 10px; width: 100%; float: clear: both;}   
}  
</style>

Comment: @Jimbly2 hit the 'share' option and from the dropdown take the code snippet from there :)

Comment: Ah - ok sorry, so links to jsfiddle not allowed.

Comment: `float: clear: both;}` - That's invalid - you should remove the `float` rule, by setting it to `none`

Comment: Maybe I should use tables? Then they could just wrap when the width hits the break point?

Comment: Well a `definition list` might make more sense, as the image is related to the text. Either way, you have invalid CSS. And another thing to mention, if you're testing this on a desktop browser: `min-device-width` won't work, you'll probably want to use `min-width` when viewing it in the browser.

Comment: Thanks Nick - was testing it directly on my phone, but good point. Which part of the css is invalid?

Comment: Are you using custom CSS to style for both Desktop and Mobile? If so that's really reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand - how so Raptus?

Comment: @Raptus Responsive design...

Comment: There are plenty of API's etc, Jquery Mobile, Bootstrap 3 and YUI that already have these purposes built in.

Comment: Bootstrap is a Framework, and generally overkill, even when you strip out the unneeded stuff. So it's not really an answer to say "Just use Bootstrap" for example.

Comment: @NickR Ok i've just tested out a stripped out Bootstrap 3 with minimum components and JavaScript and it equates to 54kb, I wouldn't say that's Overkill.

Comment: I should have said - this is a client's WP install so I'm overriding the stock CSS to make this element work how he wants. Thanks.

Comment: @NickR Could you give me a steer as to how I could implement a definition list?